# How to get the encrypted digest data from a SignedCms

Tags: c#, encryption, digital-signature

I need to verify in C# that the content of a PDF file is not modified. My approach includes obtaining the encrypted digest data from the PKCS7 and compares it to another encrypted digest which I have produced. 
I would like to achieve this only with the .NET API without using third party libraries. 
I am researching the ability to use the SignedCms class from System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs namespace. 
The SignedCms class has signedCms.SignerInfos collection from a SignerInfo object, which should hold the encrypted digest data. However, I can't find a way to access it.
Can anyone help me with this?